# Change timezone in Data studio

Tags: date, google-bigquery, timezone, looker-studio

I have a table with a `date` field UTC timezone but I want to change it into another timezone in data studio. I have created a new field in data studio with this formula: `TODATE(update_date,"America/Chicago")` but it didn't work correctly.
Any ideas? I won't change the source table to add a new column (date convert).

Answer (score 4):

Time Zone calculations can now be done in Google Data Studio using the recently introduced  ([17 Sep 2020 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020)) Date and Time functions.

### 0) [Upgrade the Date Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63926419/12892553)

Ensure that the **Date** field has been upgraded to to the newer Date field type.

Added a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

### 1) `America/Chicago`

The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below makes use of [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) in conjunction with [`CURRENT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698726) to get the difference between the two Time Zones (`UTC` and `America/Chicago`), and then subtracts the difference in `SECOND` from the Date field (named `Date` in this Report):

```
PARSE_DATETIME(
    "%s",
    CAST(CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%s", Date)AS NUMBER) - DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME("UTC"), CURRENT_DATETIME("America/Chicago"), SECOND)AS TEXT))
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1cb0b9ad-e06a-472b-a6fd-64cba7b51e0d) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the difference between two timezones is not always constant for example between winter and summer time.

Comment: @codeKonami: Could you add a couple of examples of DateTime values along with the corresponding expected output vs current output. Here's an [Editable Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tcFm_2d6F2O-QBOA1exAjx5mekmSxr7iKOqLCHYytgc/edit#gid=366718484); in any case will have a look through during the month.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this for a long time and came across so many complex indirect approaches, till I was able to implement something which seems very easy and straight forward.

Basically, in the data source connection you set up the date selection field as :

DATE('your_timefield', @timezone)

In case if using date range parameter , it would be something like :

DATE('your_timefield', @timezone)   BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) AND PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)

Next step, create a 'parameter' as below

[TimeZone parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PXxB.png)

You can select any of the timezones as 'default'

Now within your report you can publish a drop down giving users option to switch between the timezones

[timezone select Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mPWj.png)

works like a charm.
Also, while using it for things like displaying time ( in trends or otherwise) use the same parameter in selecting date/time so the time field reflects the timezone as well. you can use the datetime function as below

DATETIME("your_timefield", @timezone) as your_timefield

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with BigQuery and you're pointing directly at a table or a view, point at a SQL query instead and then use [`SELECT * REPLACE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_replace) to change to the desired timezone like so...

```
SELECT * REPLACE(DATETIME(timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles') AS timestamp) FROM dataset_name.table_name
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can manipulate the data in BigQuery, `DATE(update_date, "America/Chicago")` should do the trick.

[image: List of BigQuery's DATE function available arguments]

Comment: You failed in pointing where to find this function. This is a BigQuery feature, not Data Studio: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date